# Showing a metric space is not complete.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, cauchy-sequences

Consider the metric space $$B = \{ f \in C[0,1] : \int_a^b \left| f(x) \right| dx \leq 1\},$$ where $d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \left| f(x) - g(x) \right|dx$.

I'm trying to show that this metric space is not complete. I have proved that the metric space is not totally bounded. I did this by showing that there existed at least one sequence with a subsequence that was not Cauchy.

I'm aware that a metric space is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ Complete + Totally bounded.

Similarly, I know that compactness $\implies$ completeness, but $\neg$(compact) does not imply $\neg$(complete).

Can't seem to get the logic out.

Comment: What you want is a _Cauchy sequence_ in $(B, d)$ that _does not converge_ in $(B, d)$.

Comment: Jordan, you are not trying to prove that this space is not compact, rather that it is not complete. Here are some avenues to explore: (1) Try finding a Cauchy sequence in this space which does not converge (2) If you can find the completion of this space, you will then show that the completion and the original space are not the same (or isomorphic).

Comment: Okay, so let $(f_n) \subset B$ be a sequence such that $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{such that} \ m,n > N \implies \int_0^1 \left| f_n(x) - f_m(x) \right| dx < \epsilon.$$ Now, suppose $f_n \to f$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, consider that $$\int_0^1 \left| f_m(x) - f_n(x) \right| dx = \int_0^1 \left| f_m(x) +f(x) - f(x) - f_n(x) \right|dx \leq \int_0^1 \left| f_m(x) - f(x) \right| dx + \int_0^1 \left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right|dx = 2\epsilon.$$ By the triangle inequality... How does this arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: @Jordan you showed nothing there, just that $\epsilon<2\epsilon$...

Comment: How would you suggest I approach the problem?

Comment: It suffices to construct a _specific sequence of functions_ $(f_{n})$ in $B$, using formulas or piecewise formulas, that is Cauchy in the $1$-norm, but whose pointwise limit exists (but is discontinuous) or fails to exist.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and define
$ f_n(x) = \left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l@{}}
    0 & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1/2\\
    2nx - n & \text{if } 1/2 < x \leq (n + 1)/(2n)\\
    1 & \text{if } (n + 1)/(2n) < x \leq 1\\
  \end{array}\right.$

Then $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence whose limit is
$ f(x) = \left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l@{}}
    0 & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1/2\\
    1 & \text{if } 1/2 < x \leq 1\\
  \end{array}\right.$

because $d(f,f_n) = \int_0^1 |f(x) - f_n(x)| dx = 1/(4n)$.

Comment: $f_n$ being convergent already implies that it is Cauchy.

Comment: @Steven There is gap: For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the integral $\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx$ is not bounded by $1$. Even for $n=2$ this fails; the integral is $51/4$.